# Curl script to check IP Blacklist in an rbl via backend of Centos Server

Tags: curl, centos, blacklist

As I am working on a script I would like to ask for a suggestion on how I can check the server IP in an RBL to check whether it is blacklisted.

Answer (score 0):

RBL/DNSBL can be queried by way of DNS.  So, `curl` might not be the best tool for the job - a tool that does DNS lookups, such as `nslookup` or `host` might be better.  See http://blog.nitemayr.com/2007/05/how-to-test-an-ip-address-against-an-rbldnsbl-list/ for a good writeup on how this works.